# i have an issue with the echo command

Tags: batch-file

so this is my first line of code without youtube.
once i get down to NQ2 the code play but crashes i tested it by adding a pause after but it wont play the echo, any ideas.

```
@echo off
cls
:menu
color 9f
cls
echo hello Aidan
echo Options :
echo 1) start the game
echo 2) exit
set /p me=

if %me% == 1 goto Q/A
if %me% == 2 exit

:Q/A
cls
echo who likes pina coladas
echo 1) Rupert Holmes
echo 2) Donald Trump
set /p logo=
if %logo% == 1 goto correct
if %logo% == 2 goto incorrect 

:correct
cls
echo Yayy GOOD JOB restart(y/n)
set /p asd=

if %asd% == y goto gnv
if %asd% == n goto Next_question

:incorrect
cls
echo YOU SUCK RESTART (y/n)
set /p kld=

if %kld% == y goto gnv
if%kld% == n goto next question 2
:next_question
cls

echo whom better
echo 1) Donald trump
echo 2) Hillary clinton
set /p logo=
if %logo% == 1 goto correct 2
if %logo% == 2 goto incorrect 2

:correct 2
cls
echo congrats you not a demo crap restart (y/n)
set /p asd=
if %asd% == y goto menu
if %asd% == n goto NQ2

:incorrect 2
cls
echo your a democrap kys restart (Y/N)
set /p kld=

if %kld% == y goto menu
if %kld% == n goto NQ2
cls

:NQ2
pause
cls

echo which has more power
echo 1) C4
echo 2) TNT
if %logo% == 1 goto correct 3
if %logo% == 2 goto incorrect 3

:correct 3
cls
echo congrats your correct, c4 has about 1.2 more times the power of TNT Restart (y/n)
cls
if %asd% == goto menu
if %asd% == goto next question 2`enter `
```

Comment: for troubleshooting, don't start it with a doubleclick. Open a command window and start it from there (best without the `@echo off`). You then will see an errormessage (probably `echo was unexpected...`), followed by the failed line (probably `if == 1 goto...` (unrelated tip: labels don't support spaces) You forgot a `set /p logo=`. You may be interested in the [choice](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) command.

Answer (score 1):

Batch labels may not contain spaces, so `correct` is a label, not `correct 4`.

Comment: im a little confused what do you need me to do. is there any way for the correct spacing

Comment: Every label must be unique. Labels may not contain spaces, so `correct 4` might become `correct_4` or `correct4` for instance. Attempting to have `correct`, `correct 2` and `correct 4` will mean that `cmd` will see *each* of these labels as `correct` so the code will appear to `goto` the wrong place`